# Changing preferences.txt to 4-space tabs, how to AutoFormat existing code?

Tags: arduino-ide

Title says it all really, but to elaborate, in my `preferences.txt` file, I've changed the `editor.tabs.size` variable to `4`, which works wonderfully, and now produces 4-space tabs as do my other IDEs for all the languages I write in.

However, I was told that using the `Tools->AutoFormat` feature would update all lines in my previously-written sketches that had the standard 2-space tabs with the new 4-space tab layout.

This isn't so. Whether I `CTRL-a` to select all and run the Auto Format function, or whether I leave everything de-selected, nothing happens.

Should auto-format "fix" the 'incorrect' indenting to the new style? If so, what am I missing?

I'm currently on Arduino IDE 1.8.5 on Linux Mint, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto formatter (astyle) uses a separate configuration to the editor (crazy, I know, but that's the Arduino mentality for you...).

It uses a separate configuration, which is in the `lib` folder of your Arduino program, called `formatter.conf`.

- Copy that file to the same location as `preferences.txt` so it doesn't get overwritten when you upgrade the IDE.
- Edit the file and change `indent=spaces=2` to `indent=spaces=4`

The auto format should now be the same as the editor format.

Comment: Good grief. I'll test it here shortly @Majenko. Thanks

Comment: Wow. What a meticulously ridiculous way to do things. Answer accepted as it worked. I'll have to make notes for this and update my automation routines, as I can see this going downhill in the future on new setups.

Comment: *The auto formatter (astyle) uses a separate configuration to the editor* - with what possible justification?

Comment: @NickGammon I wish I knew. When I implemented astyle in UECIDE it just read the same formatting settings (plus extras that don't apply) for the editor...